# Python inheritance: pass all arguments from base to super class

Tags: python, inheritance

I am not quite used to class inheritance in Python yet. All I want to do is simply pass all arguments from my base class to the super class when it is created:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def do(self):
        c = self.a + self.b
        return B(c=c)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.c = c

my_A = A(a=1, b=2)
my_B = my_A.do()
print(my_B.c)
```

This works as expected. However, what I want is to also be able to call the arguments `a` and `b` from the x2 instance of the class my_B, so that I can directly write `my_B.a` for instance. I know this is done with super() like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def do(self):
        c = self.a + self.b
        return B(a=self.a, b=self.b, c=c)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        super(B, self).__init__(a=a, b=b)
        self.c = c

my_A = A(a=1, b=2)
my_B = my_A.do()
print(my_B.a)
print(my_B.b)
```

However, I don't want to explicitly write all arguments of A when I create the instance of B. Is there a way to automatically pass all arguments from class A to class B?

Comment: If class B is always instantiated from an instance of class A, then why even add a class definition for B? If you include in class A's __init__() `self.c = None`, you can mimic a B-style object by setting `my_B.c = my_B.a + my_B.b`, and you can test for a B-style object by checking `if not my_A.c: print("It's a B!")`

Comment: A parent class shouldn't have to assume the existence of any particular child. `do` seems like it should be a (class) method of `B`, rather than part of `A`.

Comment: I need a class B since class B includes some new methods which are not part of class A. B does not necessarily have to be a child of A, I just want to use the arguments and methods of class A for some methods in class B. In principle B should be the same as A, with just some added arguments which are calculated by a method in A. 

Comment: What would the ideal creation of a B object look like for you from `do()`? Something like `B(c, self)`?

Answer (score 4):

Based on your comment, you could do something like this:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, c, an_a): 
        super(B, self).__init__(an_a.a, an_a.b)
        self.c = c
```

You may instead prefer to keep your current constructor and add a `from_a` static method:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, c, a, b):  # note order
        super(B, self).__init__(a=a, b=b)
        self.c = c

    @staticmethod
    def from_a(c, an_a):
        return B(c, an_a.a, an_a.b)
```

Finally, if you don't want to type out all of those parameters, you can add an `args()` method to `A` and then use the collection unpacking function syntax:

```
class A:
    ...
    def args(self):
        return (self.a, self.b)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, c, *args):        # Note *args
        super(B, self).__init__(*args)
        self.c = c

    @staticmethod
    def from_a(c, an_a):
        return B(c, *an_a.args())
```

Now `B`'s constructor takes the parameter special to `B`, followed by any number of parameters which just get passed to `A`'s constructor. This allows you to do the tuple unpacking when calling the constructor, instead of listing everything out manually.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, thanks for your comments. I have come up with this solution:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def do(self):
        c = self.a + self.b
        return B(self, c)

class B:
    def __init__(self, base, c):
        self.base = base
        self.c = c

my_A = A(a=1, b=2)
my_B = my_A.do()
print(my_B.base.a)
print(my_B.base.b)
print(my_B.c)
```

This removes the inheritance of class B and makes the code slightly less readable, but I guess it will do, right?

Answer (score 2):

yup there is a way use key word arguments so :

```py
class A(object):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        # Non pythonic and a bit of a hack
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        vars(self).update(kwargs)

    def do(self):
        c = self.a + self.b
        return B(c=c, **kwargs)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, c, **kwargs):
        self.c = c
        super(B, self).__init__(**kwargs)

my_A = A(a=1, b=2)
my_B = my_A.do()
print(my_B.a)
print(my_B.b)
print(my_B.c)
```

This does what you are after nonethless the way in which it was written before was a bit more pythonic when run this should output:

```
1
2
3
```

The downside of doing this is that now A has not limit in terms of the number of attributes but you could ensure this with an assertion or something I guess.