# Elegant way to pass arguments to super().__init__ while keeping their name in the signatures?

Tags: python

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, x1, x2, x3, x4):
        pass
        ...

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2):
        super().__init__(x1, x2, x3, x4)  # How to replace this without repeating the argument names?
        ...
```

I prefer not to [use `**kwargs` or `dict`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32185528/python-inheritance-pass-all-arguments-from-base-to-super-class), as it hides the actual signature.

One solution could be something like:

```py
from inspect import signature

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2):
        sig = signature(super().__init__)
        params = {k: v for k, v in locals().items() if k in sig.parameters}
        super().__init__(**params)
        ...
```

But this is cumbersome and has its own problems. Is there anything more elegant that could be done?

Edit: The motivation to this question is the DRY principle.

Comment: Yes, just write it out.

Comment: Consider making `x1, x2, x3, x4` a `@dataclass`. Then you just pass this `@dataclass` by name to `super().__init__`.

Comment: Still not sure what you are proposing

Comment: I guess if `super().__init__` accepts more `*args` or `**kwargs` you could just pass all locals without filtering by signature first, but I doubt this helps readability.

Comment: And yes, sometimes you sacrifice DRY, but sacrificing DRY is much more preferable to this sort of monstrosity: `params = {k: v for k, v in locals().items() if k in sig.parameters}; super().__init__(**params)`

Comment: @tobias_k the more important thing is that it just makes your code brittle. So now you have to think, "hey, can't use a local variable or else it breaks my `super` call". That's insane. You might as well just repeat yourself.

Comment: If you go for clean code, the proposed solution is not just "cumbersome". It violates KISS, YAGNI and the principle of least astonishment.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think this should not be a problem if the call to super is the first statement in the constructor, but otherwise I entirely agree with you. I did not mean to say that this is a good idea.

Comment: Modifying the signature of child class methods (including `__init__()`) can be counter-productive especially if you have more than one child with different signature - you can’t drop one into the place of the other any more. You might be better For B to not inherit from A but use A as an attribute.

Comment: There are other ways to document what arguments `B.__init__` take. Use `kwargs`, use keyword arguments when you instantiate `B`, and let `super` do the rest.

Comment: It would be nice if there was a better acronym for "Don't repeat yourself *unnecessarily*"; DRY can be taken to extremes.

Comment: @tobias_k but again, that's exactly the problem. Now built-in to your assumption is that it will be the first line. Again, brittle. This would definitely be a problem in any codebase that involves more than one person, or heck, the same person over a span of time

Comment: Why not use `**kwargs` and then explicitly set `__signature__`?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment:

It sounds like `x1, x2, x3, x4` are logically grouped in that you see their names repeating together throughout your hierarchy of classes. You can use a `tuple` to rid of the repetition. An even better solution would be a [`@dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass), preferably read-only if the logical grouping is established at initialization time, and shouldn't be changed after. Both of these solutions would support heterogeneous types.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class X:
    x1: ...
    x2: ...
    x3: ...
    x4: ...
```

Note that you don't *need* to use a `@dataclass` here, really any class with an `__init__` method for aggregating this data and assigning it to `self` attributes would work. But `@dataclass` provides some nifty features here, see link and comments.

If the types of `x1` ... `x4` are homogenous, and you don't need to particularly enforce that there are 4 of these `x`s, you can use a `list` if you need indexing capability, otherwise `set` (and even `frozenset` to enforce this grouping to be done only at initialization time).

Point is that there is a clever solution out there to do what you want, but using structures to aggregate your data here will naturally get rid of repetition. This structure would be under a single name, and you would only have to pass this one argument to `super().__init__`.

Comment: Ok, but see, talking about `@dataclass` is sort of a red herring. This is fine with just a normal class, which is what a `@datclass` produces anyway, it simply removes boilerplate. But yes, this is usually the way to go when arguments are getting out of hand.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yup you're right, any class would really do here. But `@dataclass` does provide some nifty features, like the read-only attributes and generated `__eq__`. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: Yeah, although again I'll note, `@dataclass` just removes boilerplate, you can do all that normally.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that usually this question is to be rather avoided - better use a `dataclass` as per [Mario's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63817912/857731), or just write the arguments again as suggested in the comments.

But for the sport and the chance that this will actually be useful to someone someday, I came up with the following solution:

```py
import inspect
from functools import wraps


def calling_base_init(init):
    @wraps(init)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        sig_init = inspect.signature(init)
        bargs = sig_init.bind(*args, **kwargs)
        for cls in args[0].__class__.__bases__:
            sig = inspect.signature(cls.__init__)
            params = {k: v for k, v in bargs.arguments.items() if k in sig.parameters if k != 'self'}
            if len(params) == len(sig.parameters) - 1:
                cls.__init__(args[0], **params)
                break
        else:
            assert False, f"No appropriate signature was found among base classes of {args[0].__class__.__name__}"
        init(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

And then use the decorator on the derived class's `__init__`:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, x1, x2, x3, x4):
        print(x1, x2, x3, x4)


class B(A):
    @calling_base_init
    def __init__(self, x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2):
        print(y1, y2)


B(11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22)
```

Outputs:

```
11 12 13 14
21 22
```

as expected.